# How can I pass an Axios instance as an object or prop into a React component?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a component that I want to reuse with different Axios clients.

Example:

```
var first_instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://bank_one.com/api'
});
var second_instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://bank_two.com/api'
});

const clients = {
  first_instance,
  second_instance
};

export default clients;
```

I have a component and I want to be able to pass one of these instances as a prop or object. Something like this:

```
function BankClient({clients}){


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

  const user = {
    name: this.state.name
  };

  clients.first_instance.get(`/accounts`, { user })
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
     console.log(res.data);
   })
 }
  
  return(
    //etc etc
  )
}
```

I've tried using [this blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-pass-object-as-props) to pass objects as props but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I think  the issue is with the user(you are using this.state). Please check that and also why are you passing data in a GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the Axios instance you want to use in the component as a [prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). For example...

```jsx
import clients from "./path/to/axios-clients";
import BankClient from "./BankClient";

const App = () => (
  <BankClient client={client.first_instance} />
);
```

Within the component, use `props.client` to access it

```jsx
import { useState } from "react";

const BankClient = ({ client }) => { // destructure props.client

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { data } = await client.get(
      `/accounts/${encodeURIComponent(username)}`
    );

    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    {/* ... */}
  );
};

export default BankClient;
```

---

You appear to *want* to use [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) so be aware that the syntax is a little different to class based components.
The main thing is that you use plain functions and hooks instead of methods and `this.state`.

Comment: Thanks! I switched from function component to const BankClient = ({ client }) => {} format and it worked! I'm pretty new to react so really appreciate your response here.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, for passing data, you should either use `Post` method like so:

```js
clients.first_instance.post(`/accounts`, { user })
   .then(res => {
   console.log(res);
   console.log(res.data);
 })
```

or use `Get` method like so:

One way: Query Strings:

```js
clients.first_instance.get(`/accounts/?userName=${user.name}`)
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
     console.log(res.data);
 })
```

Another way: Path parameter (path parameters can be handled by server-side language)

```js
clients.first_instance.get(`/accounts/${user.name}`)
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
     console.log(res.data);
 })
```